# SQL Server 2008 XML Query method - retrieve text() value where another text() value exists?

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008

Please consider the following:

```
DECLARE @xml  XML
SET @xml =
'<Capture>
<Data><DataType>Card Number</DataType><Value>1234567898765</Value></Data>
<Data><DataType>Expiry Date</DataType><Value>1010</Value></Data>
</Capture>'

SELECT @xml.query('//*[text()="Expiry Date"]/text()')
```

Returns:

```
Expiry Date
```

Rather than retrieving the `<DataType/>` text node how can I retrieve the `<Value/>` text node where the text node value of `<DataType/`> is "Expiry Date"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  @xml.value('(//Data[DataType="Expiry Date"]/Value/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)')
```

You select any `<Data>` node which has the `<DataType>Expiry Date</DataType>`, and for that node, you select it's `<Value>` inner text.